# How do I get a call back for notification received in android?

Tags: android, mobile, callback, push-notification

Is it possible/is there a reliable way to get a call back when a notification is received on the android platform?  i.e.  I want to record when the notification is received (not when it is later opened).

Answer (score 0):

No, It's your app which receives the message so if you need things logged, then log it. Simply handle it as you like once you receive it. Note that if you use FCM with `Notification message` message type, then you will not be directly notified about message arrival when app is in background (notification will be automatically posted by Firebase - your app will get message payload once use taps the notification). In such case consider switching to `Data messages` so you will get it no matter your app is in foreground or not.

See docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream

Comment: "Simply handle it as you like once you receive it."
---But how? I didn't find api's about it.